# Significant Phrases

Tags: nlp

How do I extract the significant phrases from a web page text (the ones that best represent the topics of the page)?  I want to take a set of pages on the same topic (for example, pages on attractions near Altoona, PA) and get a list of the phrases that have the most information.  Not the most common, but ones that represent sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. What you're looking for is known as "n-gram analysis" and it can be completed by using the NLTK library. That will allow you to designate the type of word combinations you are looking for (2 words, 3 words, etc) and it will rank them according to how significant they are in the provided text.